# ko.toJSON() working in MVC but in asp.net FORM app "{item:" + ko.toJSON(Product) + "}" is working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am new to knockout js and i want to use knockout.js with asp.net form application . I want to update the entity using an ajax call as follow

```
// Update product details
            self.update = function () {
                var Product = self.Product();

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'SProduct.aspx/Update',
                    cache: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    data: ko.toJSON(Product),
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("success");
                        self.Products.removeAll();
                        self.Products(data); //Put the response in ObservableArray
                        self.Product(null);
                        alert("Record Updated Successfully");
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                })

            }
```

Its not working but if i change the

```
 data: ko.toJSON(Product),
```

into

```
data:"{item:" + ko.toJSON(Product) + "}",
```

Its start to call the web method .

here is my web method

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static bool Update(Product item)
    {
        Product p = new Product();
        return true;
    }
```

one more thing i want to mention that ko.toJSON() working in asp.net mvc application .

Comment: Have you tried to add the attribute [FromBody] in the WebAPI?

Comment: where should i mention this ? I am using asp.net web methods .

Comment: public static bool Update([FromBody]Product item) might do the trick. Otherwise you could look into you request with Fiddler and if there is any problem with how the data gets submitted it will show up there.

Comment: [FromBody] thats throw error The type or namespace name 'FromBody' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You can read more about the attribute over at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.frombodyattribute(v=vs.108).aspx).

Comment: do you use this code in an asp.net web form application or in an asp.net mvc application? i saw that you mentioned both

Comment: I used this in asp.net form application .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just about different mechanisms in web forms and in MVC.
In Asp.NET Web forms because the Page Method 'Update' has the parameter 'item' it is expecting a JSON object with a 'item' property so one must construct the json object in the form {"item":complexObj}.
This is true also for ASP.NET MVC, but in addition, also "data: ko.toJSON(Product)" is working because there's a 'value provider' factory which uses the Action Methods Signature to determine what Type we are expecting and it attempts to convert the input it received (from POST) into that Type. This all happens inside MVC's binding logic.

Comment: Is it not possible to do this "data: ko.toJSON(Product)" in asp.net webform application with any way ?

Comment: As far as i know no because of what i wrote above, but why isn't this syntax data:"{item:" + ko.toJSON(Product) + "}" convenient for you? Or you just have a curiosity?

Comment: If there is no way i have to stay with this, if there any way that i will like to go with that . Thanks for your time . If you find anything related to this please update your answer or comment here . Thanks once again .

Answer (score 0):

One option is to just change your WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static bool Update(Product product)
    {
        Product p = new Product();
        return true;
   }
```

Comment: Hey man you have posted same as i have and please tell me what i need to change ?

Comment: just change the name of the product object you are passing to your update function from item to product